# adding a specified comparator to java priorityqueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

Im having a hard time understanding how to priorityqueue uses the compareTo method to sort its content.

I have on class called Node.
and its has 4 fields.

```
private char character;
private int frequency;
private Node left_child;
private Node right_child;
```

Then in my other class called Huffmantree I have a priorityqueue.

My problem:

I want to put object nodes in the queue so that when dequeueing it depends on the (int)frequency of the node.

Now my Node class look like this:

```
/**
 * Class for creating nodes with a specified character, frequency, 
 *  left- and right child.
 * implements comparable to be able to compare 2 nodes based on their 
 *  frequency.
*/
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{

    private char character;
    private int frequency;
    private Node left_child;
    private Node right_child;

    public Node(char character, int frequency, Node left_child, Node 
                 right_child){

         this.character = character;
         this.frequency = frequency;
         this.left_child = left_child;
         this.right_child = right_child;
    }
    //Checks if two nodes have equal frequency.
    private boolean equals(Node n){

        return this.frequency == n.frequency;
    }



    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node other) {

        if(this.equals(other)){
            return 0;
        }else if(this.frequency > other.frequency){
            return 1;
        }else return -1;

    }

    //Print out current node
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return "[" +this.character+"," + this.frequency +"]";

    }
```

Here I have tried to implement the Comparable interface
and I have defined a CompareTo method, comparing Nodes to their frequency value.

In my HuffmanTree class I have tried to make a priorityqueue like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>()
```

but i dont know if this is how u would do it. I´m stuck and I haven't found a good example of this.

Comment: What do you want to compare?
Please specify the condition of comparing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Node` class already implements the `Comparable` interface, there is no need to define a `Comparator<Node>` and pass it to your queue object, just use the no-argument constructor :

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue()) :

> ```
> public PriorityQueue()
> ```
>
> Creates a PriorityQueue with the default
>   initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their
>   natural ordering.

In this case, you have defined a *natural ordering* by implementing the `compareTo` method for your `Node` objects, so you're pretty much done. The other constructor which takes a comparator must only be used if the elements in your queue are not `Comparable`s, or you wish to use a different ordering :

```
// This queue will hand out nodes in the inverse order of their frequency
PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node a, Node b) {
        return -a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank u! this was exactly the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: @Fanny glad to help, make sure to accept my answer so it always comes up first (and earn me some score ;) )

Comment: I'm not so used to stackoverflow but I pressed the "check" symbol and the array up hope its right :)

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo() is used to compare two objects.

So if you want to compare based on the frequency then you should write:

```
public int compareTo(Node other) {    
        if(frequency>other.frequency)
            return 1;
        else if(frequency==other.frequency) 
             return 0;
         return -1;
    }
```

Here we are comparing the current frequency with the parametrized object.

You can get a detail description from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

And you dont need this:

> PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator())

You can just write this:

> PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<>();

Comment: shouldn't you return zero if they are equal?

Comment: Yes. They should.